# How to choose a class to instantiate dynamically?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, embedded, c++20

I am working on a problem where we have an interface class with various child classes that implement the functionality of the interface. Different hardware configurations will use a child class that is most appropriate for them based on a configuration file (that is written in C++ with `constexpr`).

Initially, the intention was to use function pointers for the class constructors we wanted to use for each hardware configuration until it was discovered that function pointers to constructors are forbidden in C++. We were exploring this path as we wanted to avoid globally defined classes. The use of a factory to allow function pointers has also been considered, but I don't believe it to be ideal given the memory-constrained environment we are operating in (and the requirement for factory methods to dynamically allocate memory).

We have also been avoiding using macros to choose the implementation because we don't want to add a conditional compilation branch each time we create a new implementation of an interface in each place that the interface is used.

e.g. something to the effect of:

```cpp
#if defined(FOO)
    Foo object;
#elif defined(BAR)
    Bar object;
#elif defined(BAZ)
    Baz object;
#endif
```

Additionally, we will have a scenario where a variable number of instances of the interface will be instantiated. The number of instances will be known at compile time based on the hardware configuration and should always be relatively small (< 20). This unfortunately rules out (to my knowledge) the use of macros or the `using` declaration.

What techniques might I be overlooking that would allow me to choose the interface implementation I want to use at compile time in a config file based on the hardware configuration I am deploying to? Or if this isn't possible based on the requirements I have outlined, what might be a better strategy I should consider to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you use the STL on your device ? Which C++ standard are you using ?

Comment: "variable number of instances" ->runtime variable or depending on the device type, but fixed ?

Comment: @nick we can use the STL, but consider what we include carefully. Using C++20

Comment: Variable number that is fixed based on the hardware configuration, I will update the question to clarify

Comment: You are concerned about dynamic memory allocation but you want a variable number of instance. Can you be more specific? Have you a max number of instance? Is this number known at runtime or at compile time? You may still use a factory pattern but with memory reserved in advance (with placement new for instance, I think).

Comment: @Oersted Hopefully my edits clarify. I wasn't aware of placement new, I will need to take a look at it. At first glance it seems promising.

Comment: Then if your objects are not too large you may:
1- declare an ```std::array<uint8_t,N*sizeof(your class)>``` with N know at compile time, then placement new.
2- OR preconstruct an ```std::array<your class,N>``` with default values and post-construction initialise them, on demand.
I largely prefer solution 2 which is way cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

From the explanations, that I understood, you might be able to have a [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for your interface and child classes. With the help of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), you will be able to have an array of required (variant) instances for each configuration you set at compile time. Assuming that the `std::variant` structure doesn't spoil your hardware ROM requirements, because the `sizeof(<variant_type)` will be the max `sizeof` the child class.

[See a live demo godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qb9zjW5c6)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <array>

// Base interface class
template <typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->doSomethingImpl();
    }

private:
    constexpr Base() = default;
    friend Derived;
};

// Child class implementations
class Foo : public Base<Foo> {
public:
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    void doSomethingImpl() {
        std::cout << "Foo implementation\n";
    }
};

class Bar : public Base<Bar> {
   // ....
};

class Baz : public Base<Baz> {
   // ....
};

// Change this value to configure the hardware
constexpr short hardwareConfig = 4;  

// Implementation selection based on the configuration
template <short Config>
struct InterfaceChooser;

template <>
struct InterfaceChooser<1> {
    using Implementation = std::variant<Foo, Bar>;
};

template <>
struct InterfaceChooser<2> {
    using Implementation = std::variant<Bar, Baz>;
};

template <>
struct InterfaceChooser<3> {
    using Implementation = std::variant<Foo, Baz>;
};

template <>
struct InterfaceChooser<4> {
    using Implementation = std::variant<Foo, Bar, Baz>;
};

int main() 
{
    // Instantiate the interface using the chosen implementation based on the configuration
    using Implementation = InterfaceChooser<hardwareConfig>::Implementation;
    std::array<Implementation, std::variant_size_v<Implementation>> arrayOfObjects{
        Foo{}, Bar{}, Baz{}
    };

    // Call doSomething() for each object in arrayOfObjects
    for (auto& obj : arrayOfObjects) {
        std::visit([](auto& object) { object.doSomething(); }, obj);
    }
}
```

---

Change the `hardwareConfig` for different configurations and possibly implement the array of variants in another class template so that the child member function calls can be customized.

Comment: `std::variant` would've been my suggestion, too. The closer the different types are in size, the more efficient this will be.

Comment: `using Implementation = typename ..` - why `typename` outside of a template?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fit your need but [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) might do the job:

```
// Assuming Configuration with appropriate constexpr variables

using ObjectType = std::conditional_t<
    Configuration::use_Foo, Foo,
        std::conditional_t<Configuration::use_Bar, Bar,
            std::conditional_t<Configuration::use_Baz, Baz,
                void
            >
        >
    >;
// And then

ObjectType object;
```